# How Can I create a generic class for my blazor Model project to handle different types of json files?

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I had a task to create a generic class that can handle different types of json reponses from the backend , we will have one blazor project and 3 backend projects , this task is for the renderfragment  , they will have some " the same properties " and the others will differentiate , we have to create the class that is not fixed to any data coming from backend , they told me that i can use key value data type of enum type , i didn't know how to make it ! please i need some help

this is an example of my json response , i didn't know how to analyse it and make the class :

```
{
  "userName": "Admin",
  "history": [
    {
      "date": "02/08/2023",
      "type": "Immobilisation",
      "fiche": "37",
      "URL": "1"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "title": "Factures à importer",
      "type": "factures",
      "color": "red",
      "URL": "70"
    },
    {
      "title": "Subventions à importer",
      "type": "subventions",
      "color": "purple",
      "URL": "71"
    },
  ],
  "controls": [
    {
      "label": "Biens ayant des factures à ventiler",
      "count": "0",
      "URL": "30"
    },
  ],
  "favoritesList": {
    "setting": {
      "label": "Mes listes favorites",
      "URL": "61"
    },
    "favorites": [
      {
        "label": "100",
        "count": "0",
        "URL": "63",
        "numSep": "135220658",
        "codeSep": "S",
        "dataType": "B"
      }
    ]
  },
  "reports": {
    "setting": {
      "label": "Mes états favoris",
      "URL": "60"
    },
    "favorites": [
      {
        "label": "Actif immobilisé",
        "URL": "62",
        "numSep": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Shortcut": [
    {
      "title": "Immobilisations",
      "color": "green",
      "button": [
        {
          "label": "Créer une fiche",
          "URL": "77"
        },
        {
          "label": "Ouvrir une fiche",
          "URL": "78"
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
  "parameterList": [
    {
      "label": "Gestion des exercices",
      "URL": "80",
      "enabled": "TRUE"
    }
    {
      "label": "Gestion des imports et exports",
      "URL": "92",
      "enabled": "TRUE"
    }
  ],
  "
```

I am expecting to have a class that can handle all these json objects flexibliy , if i will add another json object to the json reponse it won't affect the class and it can handle it also , he told me that i can use enum or key value datatype , i don't know how !! any help please !!

Comment: I can't see where the differences in your JSON-structure are. Currently this is just a single structure, that you can extract classes from using any online-tool. Just search for "create classes from JSON-structure".

Comment: This is only a jsonfile from one backendproject ( the idea is each backend project will render the UI in blazor depending on the json that will provide like this one ) , the other two backend projects won't give the same Json response , so how am i able to create a generic class than can handle the responses !

Comment: if these classes don't have anything in common, there's literally nothing generic. So unless you provide what is common and what not, we can't help you.